# Compare elements in two lists in python

Tags: python, list, set, set-union

I have two lists as below:

```
a = ['abc','def', 'ghi'], b=['ZYX','WVU']
```

and want to confirm whether `union` of both lists is equal to superset

```
c = ['ZYX', 'def', 'WVU', 'ghi', 'abc']
```

I have tried following:

```
>>> print (c == list(set(b).union(c)))
>>> False
```

Can anybody show what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `set` method because the items order in the lists are different and that's why you've received `False` as result.

```
print (set(c) == set(list(set(b).union(c))))
```

Another solution is to use `Counter` class. The `Counter` approach should be more efficient for big lists since it has linear time complexity (i.e. O(n))

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(c) == Counter(list(set(b).union(c))))
```

Comment: ...or use sets on both side to spare the expensive sorting.

Comment: Thank you. I missed `set` method. I can `print (set(c) == set(b).union(c))` too.

Comment: @abhi1610, you're welcome. You can also use `Counter` method as in my answer.